# Angular 17 problem save mp3 received via Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, text-to-speech, angular17

I wrote a Web API in C# which response a google text to speech mp3 as byte array in a model with only one property named content.

If I want to save this byte array, I got a completely damaged `.mp3` file which will not be able to be played in a player.

Here is the code from my Angular download:

```
  const blob = new Blob([data.content], { type : 'audio/ogg' });
  const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = downloadURL;
  link.download = 'test.mp3';
  link.click();
```

What I tried so far:

- convert byte array to string.
- when I save the byte array directly in the API (so it will be stored on the server) the mp3 is working correctly.

So still no idea what the problem is ...

Comment: If you want an `.mp3` file - wouldn't you have to specify the `audio/mp3` media type? `audio/ogg` is an entirely different audio file type - no wonder the file can't be played as `.mp3` ....

Comment: also audio/mp3 is still not working